# Hook pre-checkout

Tags: git, git-checkout, githooks

Появилась такая проблема, что ветки по-ошибке создаются не из мастера, а из существующих ранее веток.

Решил впилить проверку на родительскую ветку в pre-checkout и был удивлен, что такого хука нет. Post-checkout есть, а pre - нет.

Единственный путь который нашел - это написать обертку над checkout, но как это реализовать - не имею представления.

Кто-то сталкивался с подобной ситуацией или знает как наваять обертку над checkout?

Comment: >`Появилась такая проблема, что ветки по-ошибке создаются не из мастера` Очень странная проблема. Может вам стоит ее решить? Или у вас разрабы создают ветки из текущих, и вы хотите зафорсить создание веток из мастера?

Answer (score 3):

Это можно сделать с помощью post-checkout хука при создании новой ветки.

Технические детали  [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011557/is-there-a-way-to-trigger-a-hook-after-a-new-branch-has-been-checked-out-in-git)

А логика в целом такая: в post-checkout, если это новая ветка, делаете `git reset --hard master`

в принципе, команды создающие ветки - `branch` и `checkout -b`, насколько я понимаю, принимают аргумент `start_point` (branch - точно), в принципе, достаточно несложно, думаю, приделать в конфиги `newbranch.default_starting_point`, и в случае его наличия запатчить branch и checkout на создание ветки из значения, выставленного в конфиге гита (ну и продавить эту идею на гитхабе торвальдсу, или кто там ответственный)

потом просто пинаете разработчиков, чтобы они проапдейтили конфиг и живете довольный